# Tableau REST API call through Browser throwing CORS error

Tags: reactjs, rest, https, cors, tableau-api

I was trying to authenticate in our Tableau Server via HTTPS. I enabled the cors in our server and add our host to the allow origin by following this documentation: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_fundamentals.htm#enabling-cors-on-tableau-server-for-the-rest-api

After restarting the server we're still facing some CORS issue when making a POST API.

Here is the screenshot of the response headers below in the actual request:

[image: Response headers of tableau server]

Here is the screenshot of the response headers below in Pre Flight request:

[image: Response of header of tableau server (PreFlight request)]

Is it something related to Web browser / Frontend? Or I'm missing some extra configuration in Tableau server?

We're using React.js in our client that is deployed in S3 Bucket with a nginx proxy server on top of it hosted in an EC2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get a solution of this?

Comment: I would also like to know if anyone figured out how to overcome this @Grayrigel